# How do I get this javascript to run every second?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do I get this javascript to run every second?

source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //More Button
    $('.more').live("click",function()  {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if(ID) {
            $("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_more.php",
                data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ol#updates").prepend(html);
                    $("#more"+ID).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('no posts to display');
        }

        return false;

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval(function () { $YOUR_CODE }, 1000);`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to run a piece of code every x milliseconds.

You can wrap the code you want to run every second in a function called `runFunction`.

So it would be:

```
var t=setInterval(runFunction,1000);
```

And to stop it, you can run:

```
clearInterval(t);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(runFunction,1000)` please. Don't pass strings. And it won't execute the code *every* second (at least there s something missing).

Comment: or [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: clean up: `var t=setInterval(mainLoop,1000);
   $( window ).unload(function() {
   
    clearInterval(t);
    console.log("Handler for .unload() called.");
       return "";
   });`

Comment: @hannunehg why?

Answer (score 12):

Use `setInterval`:

```
$(function(){
setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);
});

function oneSecondFunction() {
// stuff you want to do every second
}
```

Here's [an article](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval) on the difference between `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.  Both will provide the functionality you need, they just require different implementations.

Comment: I'm getting an error message when I tried (multiple times) to edit: "Suggested edit queue is full" (I've never seen that message before). The `about.com` link is dead. About.com was rebranded to `Dotdash.com` which split up subdomains and categories from About.com to multiple domains like `thoughtco.com` and many other verticals. According to wired.com, this happened on May 2 2017. Here is an archive copy (on Archive.org from 2016): [setTimeout or setInterval](http://web.archive.org/web/20160924165849/http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm).

Comment: Thanks @KevinFegan - not sure why you can't edit, but I've updated the link now. Good spot :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use setTimeout to run the function/command once or setInterval to run the function/command at specified intervals.

```
var a = setTimeout("alert('run just one time')",500);
var b = setInterval("alert('run each 3 seconds')",3000);

//To abort the interval you can use this:
clearInterval(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(func,1000);
```

This will run func after 1000 milliseconds. So at the end of func you can call window.setTimeout again to go in a loop of 1 sec. You just need to define a terminate condition.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
var timer = setInterval( myFunction, 1000);
```

Just declare your function as myFunction or some other name, and then don't bind it to `$('.more')`'s live event.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval(func, delay)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to run the `func` every `delay` milliseconds.

`setTimeout()` runs your function *once* after `delay` milliseconds -- it does not run it repeatedly.  A common strategy is to run your code with setTimeout and call setTimeout again at the end of your code.