# auto increment image in Image slider in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get an image slider in JQuery to move to the next image after around 2 seconds, ive tried creating a function that should do this on document load but i cant figure it out at all after about 3 hours of exhaustive Googling.

Is there a JQuery class which does this cos i cant find one...

my code for this so far :

```
        $('.slider img:first').addClass('active');                    

        var imagewidth = $('.visible-area').width();                  
        var totalimages = $('.slider img').size();                    
        var sliderwidth = imagewidth * totalimages;                   
        $('.slider').css({'width': sliderwidth}); 


        function autoImage()
        {
            nextImage();
        }

        function nextImage()
        {
            $active = $('.slider img.active').prev();                 
            if ($active.length==0){                                    
                $active = $('.slider img:last');
            }
            $('.slider img').removeClass('active');                   
            $active.addClass('active');                               

            var count = $active.attr('alt') -1;                       
            var sliderposition = count * imagewidth;                  
            $('.slider').hide();
            $('.slider').animate({'left': -sliderposition}, 500).fadeIn(1000);  
    }
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get this javascript to run every second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638783/how-do-i-get-this-javascript-to-run-every-second)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have problem with your variables declarations.

From the jQuery Api Documentation:

> The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length
>   property instead.

So use that instead for `var totalimages`

Try logging on several breakpoints to isolate problematic area(s)